# Data conversion for prime react data table component from array to JSON?

Tags: reactjs, primereact

Whenever I call a java webservice (HTTP GET) `fileLookup` with an input parameter `lookupId`, it is returning me the response in an array as shown below.

```
[
    "1224,First_File.docx,null,458,null,null",
    "1225,Second File.js,test for description,15514,778,null",
    "1226,Third_File.pdf,null,876,null,null"
]
```

The response values received corresponds to the following fields.

```
File id    File Name    Description   user Id  File Version
```

For example, in case of `1224,First_File.docx,null,458,null,null`, `1224` is the `File id`, `First_File.docx` is `File Name`, `null` is `Description`, `458` is `user Id` and `null` is `File Version` respectively.

I want to display a primereact data table, which will display above things in the table. However, most of the examples I have found are using JSON data. For example, [this sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/primereact-datatable-simple-syovz?file=/src/cars-small.json). In my case, since I don't have the data in the form of JSON object, should I consider converting the above data to JSON first so that I can supply that to Data table or anything else which can be done to achieve the same?

Comment: did you check my answer?

Comment: Thank you. I just checked it and it looks great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is sth like

[this](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-einstein-ztes5)

You create a new array where you split each string by "," and then you use the indexes as fields in `DataTable` component.

```
    <Column field="0" header="Vin" />
    <Column field="1" header="Year" />
    <Column field="2" header="Brand" />
    <Column field="3" header="Color" />
```